Philosophy as antithesis to intuition
I have recently come across a video that explains intuition and some of its challenges. One of the last challenges that came up in the video was the idea that one of the goals of philosophy is to challenge preconceptions and invent new ways of thinking, much in the same way as the empirical sciences disproved geocentirsm despite the ancients intuitively believing in geocentrism.
Are there any philosophers in history that have proposed this view? Do they expand on it? If they do, how?
Edit: Here is the video I mentioned. Also, just to make it clear, I am referring to the act of questioning the act of "questioning with intuition", not simply question with intuition.

Socrates did this literally all the time, but then so did pretty much every philosopher after him. Probably before him, too, but I don't know so much about non-western folks.

Yeah, just about every philosopher draws a distinction between appearance and actuality, and that results from language use. Maybe something in here? https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuition

Incorrect intuitions are common and are a characteristic feature of an intellectual rut that it is part of the job of good philosophy to get us out of.  I elaborated on this in this answer.

@Kevin Could you be a little bit more specific? i.e. which of Plato's dialogues include discussion about this? Thank you!

@SamCao: Literally every single time Socrates appears in any of Plato's dialogues, he's questioning somebody's intuition about something. It was his whole schtick. I would also suggest reading some Hume if you want a more contemporary philosopher who goes into greater depth about faulty intuition.

@Kevin I understand. However, are there instances of Socrates talking about the act of questioning the intuition of others?

@SamCao: Oh, you're looking for someone who talks about the act of questioning things itself? Then you probably want to read Wittgenstein.

by "anthesis" do you mean "antithesis"?

@MikhailKatz Yeah. Sorry, typo.


Philosophy as anthesis to intuition?

Maybe you meant philosophy as an antidote to intuition?
Either way, this is misguided. Intuition is essentially a cognitive capacity, something very similar to memory, logic, and our proverbial six senses. As such, you use it or you don't. Do you believe what you eyes say? Do you trust your memory? You can similarly trust or distrust your intuition. You cannot stop it, though. Your interpretation of what you are looking at as being, say, a tree, is of course not really your interpretation but one your brain produces out of the brute data coming out of your retinas. As such, this interpretation is what we could call "a sensory intuition". Looking at something, you just get the intuition that this is a tree.
Very convenient, it has to be said, but also sometimes wrong. Still, this goes very rarely wrong. Our six senses are extremely reliable, perhaps vision more than taste, but this may be my own bias. Memory is less reliable. Logical reasoning perhaps again even less reliable.
Intuitions are essentially what your brain assesses as most likely true given the data it has in store. Given this, your intuitions depend particularly on whatever you have learned. Study geometry and you will quickly get intuitions on geometry. Mathematicians have mathematical intuitions, musicians musical intuitions. These people are not going to give up on their intuitions just because some people try to give our intuition a bad name. Read Henri Poincaré or Albert Einstein, not really idiots, on what they thought about their intuitions.
The quality of your intuitions depends, probably among other things such as mental health etc., on the quality of what you have learned, whatever the way you have learned it, books or experience. This is essentially a logical process: Garbage in, garbage out. No surprise.
Given this, doing philosophy is just another way of learning something. Whether what you are going to learn through philosophy will give you smart or stupid intuitions also depends on how you do your learning. Learning by rote is probably not a good idea. Learning on a subject as you actively research it will probably produce much better results.
Obviously, what you have learned is a potential antidote to the intuitions that you would have had if you had learned it. It will be only if what you have learned someone contradicts what you believed until then. Life provides an experience which is an effective antidote to intuitions you would have from what you have learned at school.
Philosophers often go for the most fundamental questions we can ask about the world. As such, what you will learn from many if not most philosophers is more likely to provide an antidote to the sort of mundane intuitions most people get from their everyday and often repetitive experience of the world.
But so would you by studying quantum physics or general relativity, among many other sciences, or by a long enough experience of life in a different culture.
